# Mysql v5.1 vs v5.5 create table select

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding MySQL v5.1 and MySQL v5.5. I specifically would like to know what change has resulted in the following difference and what setting will make v5.5 behave the same?

**Version 5.1:**

Query: `create table if not exists _plu select * from plu limit 1 ;`

Result:
**Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)**

This will result in the table being created if it does not exist and the row being inserted into the table. If the table does exist, **the row will just be added to the table.**

**Version 5.5:**

Query: `create table if not exists _plu select * from plu limit 1 ;`

Result:
**Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)**

This will result in **no rows being inserted** if the table already exists.

What setting would i need to change in v5.5 to produce the same result in v5.1?

Comment: @Mihai : see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html. About 2/3 way down the change is discussed with reasons for it + possible workaraound.

Comment: So the change will have to be made on the query and not on the mysql server?

Comment: That's how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to get the same behavior in MySQL 5.5 because of replication issues, you can check the MySQL docs here: [Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)